# Rails application flowchart diagram generation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

While looking at existing code and my own applications, sometimes it's easy to get lost in the application logic flow in terms of where I am in the framework and what dependency files were processed before the final view.

Is there diagram generation script that is able to give a diagram of all of the dependencies from the start of a request evaluation to when a page is drawn?  Heck, I'd even not mind to be able to drill down into variables visually across the structure similar to `ddd`.

For example, it might go something like:

> other dependencies -> app/views/layout/application.html.haml ->
>   app/views/shared/_header.html.haml -> layout/application.html.haml ->
>   app/views/home/index.html.haml

If this diagram were visual then you could show loop backs or just demonstrate a hierarchy of repetitive access, or even this might work:

```
other dependencies
  app/views/layout/application.html.haml
            shared/_header.html.haml 
            home/index.html.haml
```

Ultimately something like `fseventer` app for Mac OS X could perhaps have been a close enough match, however it doesn't seem to show the shell spawned activity.  If it did it could be a wonderful example of perhaps what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for railroad.

http://railroad.rubyforge.org/

Comment: I am familiar with railroad, however I'm not seeing a way to accomplish my goal of a flowchart for the app with it. I'm really looking to create a diagram to show the flow through an app so I know what file/script is loading the next one in, etc.

Comment: I did not find anything like that, the closest I found was the depgraph that generates graphs from the require statements. I also think you've seen. http://depgraph.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately so.  It really seems as though nothing exists of this nature.  It's essentially an `fseventer` app (if you have access to a Mac) for Ruby and Rails and I think would be a really powerful asset to show your app flow while it's actually working.

Comment: Would have been nice to find something else, but I guess no one has any further input here.